# Celerybeat, celeryd Node Stopped. Running with supervisor

Tags: amazon-ec2, celery, django-celery, supervisord

I have celery running with supervisor. I am running two ec2 instances through a load balancer on AWS. One instance works while the second one gets an error when I tried running supervisorctl restart all and I got

`celerybeat: stopped
celeryd: stopped
celeryd_high: stopped
flowerd: ERROR (spawn error)
celeryd: started
celerybeat: started
celeryd_high: started`

checking the status i get

`flowerd                          FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`

my flowerd looks

`[program:flowerd]
command=/opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/django/www/src/manage.py celery flower  -A site_aggrigator -l info --address=0.0.0.0`

`stdout_logfile=/var/log/django/flowerd.log`
`stderr_logfile=/var/log/django/flowerd.log`
`autostart=true`
`autorestart=true`
`startsecs=10`
`stopwaitsecs=600`

If I make changes to one instance will it affect the other? Also I get this same log on both instances. Maybe its not the issue.

UPDATE EDIT #1: I set the startsec of flowerd to 0 and it runs fine. The only problem is that the EW2 instance spikes.